# Play local .avi videos in Node.js / Electron app

Tags: node.js, html5-video, electron

Maddening gap in an app I'm developing is there appears to be little (or no) support for AVI in the HTML5 video implementation. So, I need a workaround that is cross-platform, and package-able with my electron app.

- Videos are hosted locally
- I'm not averse to encoding on the fly (ffmpeg avi -> mp4 and use HTML5 natively?)
- WebChimera appears dying due to VLC and Electron changes (devs can't keep up) (Is there another npm package that can do this?)
- A wrapper that calls a native VLC instance might work -- but how do I ensure that VLC is available on the system with my packaging?
- Should I just spawn a native app in a separate window (ie, Totem on Linux)? (seems clunky)
- Latest videoj-java plugin apparently has issue (https://github.com/Afterster/videojs-java/issues/2) and adding another layer (java) to the electron stack seems somehow unsavory.
- FFBinaries (https://github.com/vot/ffbinaries-node) seems promising... but oddly FFPlay is not available for Linux (though I suspect my linux consumers likely have a ffmpeg already installed).

NB: Files are decidedly AVI. I can't change this.

Any hints / pointers greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

On my system, using ffmpeg to convert:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.AVI -vcodec copy -acodec copy outfile.mp4
```

Takes no time at all (they are short videos):

```
real    0m0.138s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.032s
```

So I'm leaning toward packaging ffmpeg with my program and converting before loading.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project:

- https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/electron-video-player

According to the known supported formats:

- https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/electron-video-player#known-supported-video-types

it supports:

- mp4
- webm
- ogg
- mov (MPEG4 | H.264)
- avi (MPEG4 | H.264)
- mkv (MPEG4 | H.264)
- m4v (MPEG4 | H.264)

Take a look at its source code and see if you can implement it similarly.

You said that you need AVI support but AVI is just a container - if you need other codecs than the ones supported by this project then you will still need to transcode it first.

If you cannot do it like this then you may try using something similar to:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mplayermanager

and bundle mplayer with your app, or some other player.

Comment: I downloaded that program, and it did not play my AVI videos... The codecs embedded in the AVI:  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 640x480, 2417 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 (P[0][0][0] / 0x0050), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s

Comment: I checked the source code of electron-video-player. It just depends on the browser to playback the video. There's no specific code to handle format like .avi, as asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811705/can-electron-apps-play-any-videos-supported-locally/40174631) answer, Electron now suports multiple video formats in the `<video>` tag, including `.mkv`, `.avi` and other formats. You don't need to rely on an external player.